# Data dots aren't showing up (Cartodb)

Tags: carto, network

[image: If I connect to my campus network, the map is not showing any data dots]

If I connect to my campus network, the map is not showing any data dots. And from the screenshot you can see the error messages.

[image: If I use any other network, for example using my phone's hot spot, it is fine]

If I use any other network, for example using my phone's hot spot via att lte, or comcast from my home, it is fine.

Any one knows what is happening?

Comment: I've had similar problems with my home network and networks outside my home... also: please give a bit more information as to the system you're using (CartoDB) and what you're working with (Visualization)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. But I don't understand what kind of "system(CartoDB)" are you referring to.

Comment: you didn't explain what this map is, how it was made, where the data is coming from, how you've built this app, etc.

Comment: So this is a map about some food energy system around the world, with coordinates and corresponding names, descriptions. I upload an excel file to create a table. Then I visualize it with cartodb visualize queue. At last, I copy autom-gernerated iframe code into my own wordpress page.

Comment: This seems to be provoked by a firewall blocking the tiles. Could you try to embed the map via HTTPS? Remember that for that you need to modify the URL of the libraries.

Comment: Hi iriberri, I don't quite entirely understand what do you mean. I try use https when in front of the viz.json uri. But it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iriberri is correct. I need to specify protocol in the options field, like this.

```
cartodb.createLayer(map, layerUrl, {'https':true})
```

Whiel the `layerUrl` is not necessarily https.